# No input file specified. - Magento 2.0.2/Vagrant/Virtualbox/Homestead

Tags: .htaccess, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, magento-2.0

I'm having trouble installing Magento 2.0.2. 
Created project through composer, and when it is time to get Magento installed I get this - No input file specified.
I saw solution for godaddy hosting with .htaccess, tried it, still getting same error.

```
.htaccess

Added:

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+.php$ /bogusfile

Options +ExecCGI 

Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
AddHandler php5-cgi .php

In php5.ini

Added:

cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all, I know that Homestead coming with the nginx with the out off the box, so you can't manipulate nginx's behaviors with .httacces file. nginx isn't use .httaccess

I have 2 recommendations for you:

1- Double check folder and site settings in your Homestead.yaml file  if these

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

folders are really exist and pointing correct directories for both host and server.

2- If you are using Windows 10 on your PC, you have to be sure that you are not using some incompatible versions of Oracle VM.